# What is the center of gravity for a quarter parabolic elips?

Tags: geometry, gravity, centroid, hyperbolic-function

I could not find anywhere the center of gravity for half of the parabolic elips area (shown in figure) which formula is x^n+y^n=1, starting from a x,y value. I need parametric answer but if not possible, n might be assumed as 4 and x,y(0.4,0.4) as shown in figure.
[image: figure]

[image: figure]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has no relation to programming

Comment: Its about a q rung orthopair fuzzy distance measure which might be used in classification or decision making...

Comment: In any case you need to calculate double integrals - using hypergeometric function or using numerical integration methods.